# Limit points of the set

Tags: real-analysis, limits

What are the limit points of the set $$\left\{\frac{1}{n}\sin \left(\frac{1}{n} \right):n\in\mathbb N\right\}?$$

Since $$0\le \left|\frac{1}{n}\sin \left(\frac{1}{n} \right) \right|\le\frac{1}{n}\to 0$$ so $$ \left| \frac{1}{n} \sin \left(\frac{1}{n} \right) \right| \to 0 \implies \frac{1}{n}\sin \left(\frac{1}{n} \right)\to0$$

So $0$ is the only limit point of the set.

Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. A point $x \in \Bbb R$ is a limit point of your set iff there is some sequence with infinitely many distinct terms converging to it. Since every sequence with infinitely many elements of your set converges to $0, 0$ is the only limit point.

Comment: why $0$ is only limit point?